# Adding iterative group of algorithms to QGIS model

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, iteration

In a QGIS model, I have a section in the workflow where a certain group of algorithms (let's say: do A, then B, then C, then D: see below for details) has to be re-run until a condition is met. So depending on the input data, the group of algorithms should run twice, three, four, five times etc. - each time checking after finishing it if the condition is met. If not: restart the algorithm group, otherwise go further in the model.

So I don't want to run the whole model in batch mode, but to include a recursive part into the model itself.

I looked into the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/processing/modeler_twi.html) and I know there is a conditional branch and I also know that you can include other models (e.g. the algorithm group A to D) into a model.

However, is it possible to run it iteratively and how?

---

The input is a layer with several multipart line features. They should all connected together, each with the nearest neighboring feature, until finally all lines are connected to to contiguous network. The algorithm group does this:

1. Connect each line to the closest neighboring line feature
2. Merge output of 1 with the lines from the input
3. Buffer/dissolve merged lines from 2 (with the option of keeping disjoint features separate)
4. Merge all lines inside each buffer to a multipart feature.

Check how many features the result has: if only one, all lines are connected, stop iteration. If larger then 1, repeat 1 to 4.